# How to express in a diplomatic, but not too subtle, way that an old (and popular) notion should be dismissed in favor of a new (and better) one?

Tags: expressions

I'm comparing two (mathematical) notions, say 'functoid' and 'punctoid' (these are fictitious names for the sake of discussion), and I'm arguing that punctoids should be definitely preferred to functoids for a series of reasons.

To convey this idea, I would like to use an expression that is neither too strong nor too subtle. I have been thinking about something like the following:

> In a way, what we have just remarked makes the notion of functoid à la Craig and Daniel *overruled* by punctoids.

But I'm not sure about my use of the term 'overruled'. I had also thought of replacing it with 'shelved', but this sounds too soft to my ears. Please note that I need to stick to a formal register, as this is intended for a publication.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could joking say that *functoids* are *passe*, or [*yesterday's news*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/yesterday's_news).

Comment: What does *à la Craig* mean? is this a new saying?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I can't. :-) I should really stick to a formal register. As for the "à la Craig and Daniel", I think it means "in the sense of Craig and Daniel" (or, at least, this is what *I* mean!): It comes from French, but I think it's common in English (at least in mathematical publication).

Comment: Mari-LouA: Got it. I will edit and add it to the OP. 
Dan Bron: Thanks, I like both of your susggestions! Somehow, I seem to prefer "obsoleted": I will probably run into troubles... :)

Comment: You should wait a bit before accepting, not saying supercede isn't correct, but it gives folks time to come up with other suggestions. I'm sure @ab2 wouldn't object....too much.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: Got it.

Comment: An aside:  "Supercede has occurred as a spelling variant of supersede since the 17th century, and it is common in current published writing. It continues, however, to be widely regarded as an error", from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supercede)

Comment: You see "a la" a lot, mostly used wrongly; "la" means it's female. If you want it to be "in the style of so-and-so" and so-and-so is male, you need to say "au". But basically I'd say if you are not writing French, or a recipe book, stay away from "a la" and say "in the style of" or "as performed by".

Comment: @RedSonja I think "a la" is short for the French expression "à la manière de" or " à la mode de", so there is no real issue with gender.

Comment: Just an aside, but *what we have just remarked makes* is a pretty awkward construction here. I would consider revising that portion of the sentence as well.

Comment: @RedSonja It might be wrong if it was used in French, but it’s not here. In English, *a la* or *à la* simply means “in the sense of” or “in the mode of” as a stock phrase. English, being an ungendered language, simply borrowed a useful phrase from another language—as it often does—and uses it its own way—again, as it often does. You can object to the propensity of the English language for this kind of behavior if you want, but ignoring the reality of it doesn’t help you—and encouraging others to avoid useful phrases based on ignoring that reality doesn’t help them, either.

Comment: I would avoid the word "we" unless there are multiple authors of the paper.  Otherwise, as a general rule in all my writing, I try to be as simple and direct as I can.  A writer of any kind always has a tenuous hold on the attention of his or her reader and risks loss of the same by taking too long to get to the point or making the reader work too hard to figure out what the writer means or is trying to say.

Comment: @KRyan. Thanks for the explanation. I just want to add that *à la* is not wrong in French either: For instance, we often say and write "intégration à la Lebesgue", where Lebesgue is *Mr.* Henri Léon Lebesgue, the father of modern integration theory. Again, the point is that "à la" is short for "à la manière de". We have a similar expression in Italian (my mother tongue): We say, e.g., "integrazione alla Lebesgue", where "alla" is what we call an "articulated preposition" (nothing similar exists in English), made up of "a" (a simple preposition) and "la" (a feminine definite article).

Comment: @KenClement My last comment and yours are swapped in the order, because I had to rewrite mine. In any case, the use of "we" in mathematical writing is widespread, regardless of the number of authors: My understanding is that we use it to convey either the idea that it's not the author, but a part of the whole (mathematical) community that is making a certain statement, or the idea that authors and readers sit side by side to each other while the paper is being written: For some of us, mathematics is plural. Not as a noun, but as a form of art.

Comment: Ok all, I was wrong about "a la" and I shall not be irritated by it ever again. It still feels wrong, though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

***supersede***, as defined by [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/supersede)

> to set aside or cause to be set aside as void, useless, or obsolete,
>   usually in favor of something mentioned; make obsolete:  They
>   superseded the old statute with a new one.

Steven Weinberg (Nobel Prize winner in Physics, 1979) used **supersede** in this way in his book [*Lectures on Quantum Mechanics*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7flfCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=matrix+mechanics+superseded&source=bl&ots=iIcucU4hbT&sig=XR3TqLFLw5qNHl51H3Ws94WRACY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiX9f2-hIfTAhUBWRQKHUwoB1cQ6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=matrix%20mechanics%20superseded&f=false), page 21:

> It was hopeless to use matrix mechanics to solve more complicated
>   problems, like the hydrogen molecule, so wave mechanics largely
>   superseded matrix mechanixs among the tools of theoretical physics.

The OP's sentence thus becomes:

> In a way, what we have just remarked makes the notion of functoid à la
>   Craig and Daniel superseded by punctoids.

I suggest rewriting the sentence to say:

> In a way, what we have just remarked means that punctiods supersede
>   the notion of functoids a la Craig and Daniel.

*Footnote about the use of a la* in a math article:  See [Using the Mathematics Literature](https://books.google.com/books?id=i2mu7jg6OHEC&pg=PA182&lpg=PA182&dq=%22a+la%22+in+mathematics+literature&source=bl&ots=vIUdsm7qvr&sig=E5em57ZHj9fvJHuHrFmxsDEfCAs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih5fj3iYfTAhUJwxQKHYjrDFoQ6AEINTAF#v=onepage&q=%22a%20la%22%20in%20mathematics%20literature&f=false).

Comment: With respect, *supersede* does describe the meaning OP was asking about but no one would/should actually write "X means that Ys supersede the notion of Zs". He's not really talking about a law that was replaced by a recent enactment.

Comment: At least to my mind and sense of the language (I'm not a kid anymore...), "supersede" does exactly convey the intended sense, namely, of rendering the other thing archaic or obsolete.

Answer (score 8):

Consider "deprecated".  See https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/deprecate, however.

According to this note, it's been used since the 1980s to imply obsolescence, although MW questions this use.

You can be more positive by noting that the punctoid is superior or better in a variety of ways (more flexible, less prone to error, whatever).

Thus:

> The functoid should be deprecated in favor of the punctoid.

A milder approach is to say that the funtcoid approach should be replaced.

Comment: You have to use blank lines between paragraphs or else they will not format correctly.

Answer (score 7):

> In a way, what we have just remarked makes the notion of functoid à la Craig and Daniel overruled by punctoids.

*Overruled* is the wrong word since the punctoids are not sitting in judgment over the functoids, but the real problem with the phrasing is the *makes*. What you've just shown (supposedly) ***proves*** that functoid is ***inferior*** (not as good) or ***obsolete*** (no good at all any longer).

You can certainly use *à la* but in English it's associated with ice cream and is precious verging on twee. You were trying to avoid sounding weak, so you need a substitute.

*In a way* is just incorrect. Either you've established the point or you haven't. (If it's the latter, you shouldn't be saying the functoids are obsolete at all.)

> These factors establish that Craig and Daniel's notion of functoid is fundamentally inferior to XYZ's punctoid.

or

> These considerations, taken together, show that the notion of functoid (as seen, e.g., in Craig and Daniel) has been rendered obsolete by punctoid.

Comment: My addition to *rendered obsolete*, you may capture the same sense in a single word using the transitive *obsoleted*. +1.

Comment: @Dan Bron isn't wrong, but some readers doubleminus verbing nouns.

Comment: I doubleminus those doubleminusers.

Comment: @Dan Bron which is fine for a Don Delillo novel but Mr Tringali was saying his paper was so formal he shouldn't use the expression *passé*. In any case, yes, perfectly terser for informal situations.

Comment: I believe _obsolesced_ is a more proper version of _obsoleted_.

Comment: I thought a la was strange in this context too, but see [Using the Mathematics Literature](https://books.google.com/books?id=i2mu7jg6OHEC&pg=PA182&lpg=PA182&dq=%22a+la%22+in+mathematics+literature&source=bl&ots=vIUdsm7qvr&sig=E5em57ZHj9fvJHuHrFmxsDEfCAs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih5fj3iYfTAhUJwxQKHYjrDFoQ6AEINTAF#v=onepage&q=%22a%20la%22%20in%20mathematics%20literature&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

It’s not often used, but should be recognizable and understood:

**Obsolesce**

> *Transitive Verb*
>
> : to make obsolescent

<sup>([Meriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsolesce))</sup>

where *obsolescent* means *becoming obsolete*, and *obsolete* is a fairly common word. It has precisely the meaning you intend, and that meaning is clear to anyone familiar with *obsolete*, which most English-speakers are.

So your statement could be

> In a way, what we have just remarked makes the notion of functoid à la Craig and Daniel *obsolesced* by punctoids.